# Flushing rewrite rules in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to programmatically add a rewrite rule in wordpress using their rewrite functions. Typically it looks like this is used in conjunction with a plugin init or activate function so that the rewrite rules flush is only called once.

I'm not doing this in conjunction with a new plugin install, so where should I put these functions and calls so that I can call them once?

I'm going to add a rewrite rule as described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Permalinks_for_Custom_Archives

Just not sure where to put this code.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding a custom theme you can put all your code in `functions.php`. Nevertheless, what is stopping you from creating a plugin for your own use?

Comment: I can put it in functions.php but where do I call the flush command from? I basically need to call this stuff once. A flush and add the rule. What calls the flush and the addition of the rule? Sorry I am probably confused as to how this all works. Thanks.

Comment: There is a hook available called switch_theme which is triggered every time the active theme is changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't switch my theme because we have a live site with some variables that will get messed up if I change the theme. Is there another option to call this stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Well then you will have to generate manually the rewrite rules. As I have already suggested, add your custom code in `functions.php` and then via WP Administration > Settings > Permalinks manually re-generate the rewrite rules (just hit "Save changes").

Comment: Also, keep in mind that editing your theme files directly in the production environment (live site) is not considered as a good practise. Consider to maintain a development copy, making all the changes necessary and when you are done you can safely deploying them to the production env.